# objective c Regular expression 3

Tags: regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I have a `NSString` like this.

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: success in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1225</b><br /><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit ( in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit n in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit u in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit l in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit l in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br />

<b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit ) in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br />

 <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: success in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line 
    <b>1225</b><br />{"success":1,"success_message":"Edit listing success"}
```

How do I extract this `{"success":1,"success_message":"Edit listing success"}`part.

Comment: Isn't that string coming from a complete JSON response from some web service?

Comment: Cut string with starting character "{" and ending character "}". BINGO !!! You will get your desired string but this will work only if your response in coming in above mention format. Also do check with above comment.

Comment: Might I humbly suggest that fixing the errors on your server then parsing the response as pure JSON is a fix that is smarter, better, easier, and many other -er words? :)

Comment: mhmm service is not done my me. and this is what I get after doing my task in my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as that's the general format of your strings, the pattern `(\\{[^}]+\\})` ought to do it. Here is some example code to get you started:

```
NSString *test = @"<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: success in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1225</b><br /><br /><b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit ( in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br /><b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit n in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br /><b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit u in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br /><b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit l in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br /><b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit l in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br /><b>Warning</b>:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit ) in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1434</b><br /><br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: success in <b>/var/www/webservice/gcm/setMessage.php</b> on line <b>1225</b><br />{\"success\":1,\"success_message\":\"Edit listing success\"}";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(\\{[^}]+\\})" options:0 error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *result = [regex firstMatchInString:test options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, test.length)];
NSString *match = [test substringWithRange:result.range];

NSLog(@"Matched %@", match);
```

You should obviously handle errors more gracefully than just ignoring them.